# Is there a way to group rows based on cell value in a particular column into named range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, named-ranges

I am collecting the vaccination records of all employees in my company via Google Form, the form collects their vaccination status and which department they are from. I used **Named Range** to group responses from the same department to do some COUNTIF. The problem I encounter is that every time when there is a new submission, I have to manually adjust the named range in order to include that new response in the analysis. I wonder is there a way to automatically update the named range based on the department

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use open-ended references like `D2:D` instead of named ranges.

Assuming the department names are in column `'Form responses 1'!D2:D`, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=query( 
  'Form responses 1'!A2:F, 
  "select D, count(D) 
   where D is not null 
   group by D", 
  1 
)
```

To count responses individually for each category in column `B`, use `pivot`, like this:

```
=query( 
  'Form responses 1'!A2:F, 
  "select D, count(D) 
   where D is not null 
   group by D 
   pivot B", 
  1 
)
```

See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax) for more options.

Comment: Thank you! May I know if there's a way where I can count the number of different responses within the same department? The responses to "How many shots have you taken?" are in column 'Form responses 1!B2:B', and I want to count how many people select 0/1/2/3/not willing to disclose within the same department

Comment: Edited the answer to add a `pivot`. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Overflow. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)